# Pandas filtering argument of type function is not iterable

Tags: python, database, pandas

I am using PyThon with Pandas.

In the context of tennis matches, I would like to filter my data in the following way:

- Check that the winner is a certain player
- Check that the loser is within a specified set

I am trying to do it in the following way

```
filtered_data = df[(df.winner == player) & (df.losser in desirable_opponents)]
```

where df is a DataFrame object storing my data.

I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: argument of type 'function' is not iterable
```

I understand the error. But I have not come up with a way to fix it.

How could I do the filtering such that df.loser is checked against many values, instead of just one like df.winner == player?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should use [**`isin`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html)

```
filtered_data = df[(df.winner == player) & (df.losser.isin(desirable_opponents))]
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew that there had to be a way to solve this using less than 10 extra characters.

Answer (score 3):

Consider also SQL-like [query](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) method:

```
filtered_data = df.query("winner == @player and losser in @desirable_opponents")
```

where `player` is a scalar variable and `desirable_opponents` is an array-like variable (list, 1D array, Pandas.Series, etc.)

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the answer. I have decided to choose the other one as the real answer just because it was closer to my original design

Comment: @DanielHernandez, sure ! :-)